# Prove that a sub-Gaussian random vector over a finite set $S \subset\mathbb R^n$ implies that $|S|$ is exponentially large

Tags: pr.probability

Let $X$ be an isotropic random vector (i.e. $E[XX^T]=I_n$) and $X$ takes value in a finite set $S \subset\mathbb R^n$. If $X$ is a sub-Gaussian random vector and the norm $\|X\|_{\psi_2}\le C$ where $C$ is a constant, it will imply that $S$ is expoentially large with dimension $n$.

Note that $X$ is said to be sub-Gaussian with norm $K$ iff the marginal distribution in any direction is a sub-Gaussian with norm less or equal than $K$.

For example, if $X$ is uniformly distributed in $\{-1,+1\}^n$, then $X$ is a sub-Gaussian random vector with constant norm but now $|S|=2^n$. (It can be proved)

How can I prove the proposition? I just have no idea to deal with the "exponential" proof. Thank you!

Comment: Note that this is exercise 3.4.5 in Vershynin's *High Dimensional Probability* (though there is no proof there).

Answer (score 11, accepted):

If $(Z_i)_{1 \leq i \leq N}$ are scalar random variables with $\|Z_i\|_{\Psi_2} \leq C$, then $\mathbf{E} \max Z_i \leq CC'\sqrt{\log N}$ by the usual union bound argument.

Now let $X$ be an isotropic random vector in $\mathbf{R}^n$ such that $\|\langle X,\theta \rangle \|_{\Psi_2} \leq C $ for every unit vector $\theta$, and let $S$ be the support of $X$. Choose a number $A$ such that $S$ is contained in the ball of radius $A\sqrt{n}$. Since (denoting by $\|\cdot\|$ the Euclidean norm)
$$ ||X||^2 \leq \sup_{x \in S} |\langle X,x\rangle|, $$
it follows from the aforementioned estimate that
$$ n = \mathbf{E} ||X||^2 \leq A \sqrt{n} CC'\sqrt{\log |S|}.$$
In particular, we get $|S| \geq \exp(c(A,C) n)$.

We are going to reduce to the situation where $A$ is bounded. To that end, 
take an isotropic subgaussian random vector $X$ with $||\langle X,\theta \rangle||_{\Psi_2} \leq C$. This implies in particular $\mathbf{E} \langle X,\theta \rangle^4 \leq 4C^2$ (possibly change $4$ into another number depending on which definition of $\|\cdot\|_{\psi_2}$ you use). Define a new random vector as $Y = X {\bf 1}_{\{ ||X|| \leq 4C \sqrt{n}\} }$. The vector $Y$ is not exactly isotropic but satisfies $\frac 12 I_n \leq \mathbf{E} YY^T \leq I_n$. This is because (by Cauchy-Schwarz and Markov inequalities)
$$ \mathbf{E} \left[ \langle X,\theta \rangle^2 {\bf 1}_{\{||X|| > 4C \sqrt{n}\}} \right] \leq \left( \mathbf{E} \left[ \langle X,\theta \rangle^4 \right] \cdot \mathbf{P}(||X||^2 > 16C^2n)\right)^{1/2} \leq \sqrt{\frac{4C^2}{16C^2}} = \frac{1}{2}$$

We are now going to apply the first part of the argument to a linear image $\tilde{Y}$ of $Y$ which is isotropic. The random vector $\tilde{Y}$ is supported in the ball of radius $A\sqrt{n}$ for $A=8C$, and satisfies $\|\langle \tilde{Y},\theta \rangle \|_{\Psi_2} \leq 2C$, so the support of $Y$ (which is contained into $S \cup \{0\}$) contains at least $\exp(c(8C,2C)n)$ points.

Comment: Very nice! Only I don't see how and why you would use Paley--Zygmund, instead of just writing $E(a\cdot X)^2\,1_{\|X\|>\sqrt n}\le E\|X\|^2\,1_{\|X\|>\sqrt n}\to0$ as $n\to\infty$, for any unit vector $a$.

Comment: I wanted to compare 2nd with 4th moment. But yes there is a simpler argument along the lines you suggest, I will include it.

Comment: Do you define $\tilde{Y}:=\text{E}(YY^T)^{-\frac{1}{2}}Y?$ If yes, could you explain how to get that $\lVert \langle \tilde{Y},\theta \rangle \rVert_{\psi_2}\leq 2C$ for all unit vectors $\theta$ holds.

Comment: Yes $\tilde{Y} = T^{-1/2}(Y)$ for $T=\mathbf{E} [ YY^T]$. Now, observe that $\langle \tilde{Y}, \theta \rangle$ is the same as $\langle Y, T^{-1/2} \theta \rangle$ and therefore $\| \langle \tilde{Y}, \theta \rangle \|_{\psi_2} \leq C \|T^{-1/2} \theta \| \leq \sqrt{2}C$.

Answer (score 1):

$\DeclareMathOperator*{\E}{\mathbb E}\DeclareMathOperator*{\tr}{\mathsf{tr}}\DeclareMathOperator*{\PP}{\mathbb P}\DeclareMathOperator{\D}{d \negthinspace}$By definition of isotropic vectors, $\E \left(X X^T\right) = I_n$. Taking trace, $\E \tr\left(X X^T\right) = \E \tr\left(X^TX \right) = \E \lVert X \rVert_2^2 = n$.

Let $\lVert X \rVert_{\psi_2} = t$. For all $u \in T$, we have $\lVert \langle u, X \rangle \rVert_{\psi_2} \le t$, implying
\begin{align}
    & \E \exp \left(\lVert X \rVert_2^2 / t^2\right)\\
    =& \sum_{u \in T} \PP \{X = u\} \exp(\lVert u \rVert_2^2 / t^2)\\
    \le & \sum_{u \in T} \E \exp(\langle u, X \rangle^2 / t)\\
    \le & 2|T|.
   \end{align}

We use this information to bound the second moment. Let $B > 0$. We split the integral identity into two pieces $\le B$ and $>B$.
\begin{align}
    n & = \E \lVert X \rVert_2^2 \\
      & = \int_0^\infty \PP \{\lVert X \rVert_2^2 > x\} \D x\\
      & \le B + \int_{B}^\infty \exp(-x/t^2) \E \exp \left(\lVert X \rVert_2^2 / t^2\right) \D x\\
      & \le B + 2|T| \int_{B}^\infty \exp(-x/t^2) \D x\\
      & = B + 2|T|t^2 \exp(-B/t^2)
   \end{align}
Optimizing the RHS, we take $B = t^2 \log(2T)$ and yield $n \le t^2 (\log(2|T|) + 1)$. This reads $|T| \ge \frac{1}{2e} \exp(n/t^2)$, as desired.

Comment: Very nice. The integral-split part can be shortened using $\exp(n/t^2)\le E\exp(\|X\|^2/t^2)\le 2|T|$ by Jensen's inequality.

Answer (score 0):

This conjecture is false. Indeed, let, as in your example, $X$ be uniformly distributed on $\{-1,1\}^n$. Let $Y$ be a random vector uniformly distributed on the set $$S_Y:=\{\sqrt n\,e_1,-\sqrt n\,e_1,\dots,\sqrt n\,e_n,-\sqrt n\,e_n\},$$ where $(e_1,\dots,e_n)$ is the standard basis of $\mathbb R^n$. Then $EYY^T=I_n=EXX^T$. Also, $\|Y\|=\sqrt n=\|X\|$, where $\|\cdot\|$ is the Euclidean norm, so that $Y$ is sub-Gaussian in exactly the same sense as $X$ is. However, $|S_Y|=2n=o(e^{an})$ as $n\to\infty$ for any constant $a>0$.

Comment: I think the OP means by subgaussian that all 1-dimensional marginals of $X$ have to be (uniformly) subgaussian

Comment: @GuillaumeAubrun : Where do you see any hint about or any mentioning of one-dimensional marginals? Rather to the contrary, in the description of the example in the OP only the constant norm of $X$ is mentioned.

Comment: I've seen this terminology used by people working in high-dimensional probability/convex geometry

Comment: But why do you think that usage would apply here, especially given that in the description of the example in the OP only the constant norm of $X$ is mentioned?

Comment: Well, maybe I'm wrong about what the OP meant, but this interpretation makes the question much more interesting :-)

Comment: @GuillaumeAubrun : With your latter comment I agree, but that would be another question.

Comment: I am sorry that I didn't give the definition of $\|\cdot\|_{\psi_2}$ of a random vector. It has the same meaning as @Guillaume Aubrun said. I have added it in the question.