# Lower bounds for sub-Gaussians?

Tags: pr.probability, orlicz-spaces

For a random variable $X$, define

$$\lVert X\rVert_{\psi_2} =\inf \{k>0\mid \mathbb{E}[\exp((X/k)^2)]\leq 2\}$$

and for a random vector $\vec X$, define

$$\lVert \vec X\rVert_{\psi_2} = \sup_{\theta : \lVert \theta\rVert_2 = 1} \lVert \langle \vec X, \theta\rangle\rVert_{\psi_2}.$$

I'm interested in conditions which imply that $\lVert X\rVert_{\psi_2}$ (or $\lVert \vec X\rVert_{\psi_2}$) are large.
I am in particular interested in quantitative/"fine-grained" results, e.g. statements such as

> If (some condition depending on $K$ holds) then $\lVert X\rVert_{\psi_2} \geq f(K)$ for some function $f$

Examples of such conditions that I am aware of essentially boil down to converses for the standard equivalences between various definitions for sub-gaussianity (see [Vershynin prop 2.5.2](https://www.math.uci.edu/%7Ervershyn/papers/HDP-book/HDP-book.pdf)). For example

1. The moments $\mathbb{E}[|X|^p]^{1/p} \geq K\sqrt{p}$ for all $p\geq 1$,
2. If $\mathbb{E}[X] = 0$, then for all $\lambda>0$ $\mathbb{E}[\exp(\lambda X)] \geq \exp(K^2 \lambda^2)$

One example I know of that does not follow this naive trend is Exercise 3.4.5 of Vershynin (also located [here](https://mathoverflow.net/questions/326033/prove-that-a-sub-gaussian-random-vector-over-a-finite-set-s-subset-mathbb-rn#comment1176081_326033)), namely that if $\lVert \vec X\rVert_{\psi_2} =O(1)$ is constant independently of the dimension of $\vec X$, and $\vec X$ is supported on a finite set, then that set must have exponentially large cardinality.

Are there other results which are useful for showing a random variable $X$ does not have small sub-Gaussian parameter?

Comment: It is a bit unclear what you are asking. Perhaps the small ball probability results are useful to you: http://jamesyli.com/wenbo_li/papers/01-survey-LiShao.pdf "Gaussian Processes: Inequalities, Small Ball Probabilities and Applications".

Comment: If you have some specific random variable/process in mind, it can be easier to check for some conditions. But in such general setting, is hard to say anything.